# Embedding a dynamic file using the "view file" macro

Tags: confluence

The [`view file`](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/View+File+Macro) macro allows embedding documents (*.ppt*, *.pdf*, etc) on a *Confluence* wiki page. Limitation is, documents must be on attachments.

So question, is there a way to load dynamically a file located into an SCM's deposit?

**P.S.** Current SCM: Perforce.

**UPDATE**: As I see, there is no official *Perforce* plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You may of course include a link to that file, if Perforce provides a way to link items. We use that a lot, to include content that is stored in Subversion, and document the standing, the usage, ... in Confluence then. The user has to click on that link to get that file, but I think it is necessary anyway, because your authorization rules are not known to Confluence.

Comment: No, a simple link to the file cannot work, because the path is variable (depending on the local workspace arrangement).

Comment: I did not know that ... Then I see no way to make it work. This would mean that you need a plugin that needs to read out the local workspace location in some way, so that the display of the page will be individualized for each reader. See no way to get something like that.